# how to handle two buckets in firebase storage when uploading files to firebase using angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, buckets

in app.module

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)
```

I have two storage

```
firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyBHsAxVgiuM0_xLd3BunTG6Yf9x1nynxoA',
    authDomain: 'careerograph-e9963.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://careerograph-e9963.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'careerograph-e9963',
    storageBucket: 'careerograph-e9963.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '669874223858'
  },
  firebaseExcelConfig: {
    apiKey: 'AIzaSyBHsAxVgiuM0_xLd3BunTG6Yf9x1nynxoA',
    authDomain: 'careerograph-e9963.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://careerograph-e9963.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: 'careerograph-e9963',
    messagingSenderId: '669874223858',
    storageBucket: 'careerograph-excel',
  },
```

in component I inject in contructor private storage: AngularFireStorage
then call

```
this.task = this.storage.upload(this.path, file, { customMetadata });
```

How can I choose a bucket to upload file to it

Comment: Before asking a question, please be sure the [read the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start#use_multiple_storage_buckets).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is provided in the official documentation of the library.

Comment: I want to use upload method and it is not available to firebase

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?  In answer to the comment above the question is about angularfire storage and the docs are for pure firebase.

Comment: @MadMac , No I didn't get a solution

Answer (score 3):

In the documentation you can see:

```
// Get a non-default Storage bucket
var storage = firebase.app().storage('gs://my-custom-bucket');
```

The reference of the storage you have to define is in this way:

```
var storageRef = firebase.app().storage('my-custom-bucket').ref();
```